# Centos .netcore The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1" were not found

Tags: c#, frameworks, .net-core, upgrade

I have a C# .NET app that is currently running in Windows Server 2012. I wish to move that app to run on Centos with .NetCore installed. When I try to run the app using `dotnet run --project 'foldername'` I get the error

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1" were not found

The FW is available from MS but they are in .exe. How does one install that FW on Centos .NetCore. Basically, how do I upgrade my FW on Centos .NetCore

Comment: Trademark capitalization; layout.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert your .NETFramework projects to .NETCore and .NETStandard projects, than you can use the created .dll-s in CentOS with the .NETCore.
Where you can, I recommend the .NETStandard, because you will be able to use it everywhere later (.NETCore, .NETFramework, Xamarin, UWP).

I suggest you, to make some research in the topic.

.NET Standard:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

.NET Core 2.0:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/

Porting to .NET Core:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/libraries